# Display list of terms having the same custom field value

Tags: custom-field, terms

I have a custom field for my taxonomy called `'food_type'`.

How can I display a list of my terms where this custom field's value is set to "Cat food"?

Answer (score 2):

To do that, you'll need a custom query - Wordpress doesn't have a ready-made function for getting that type of data from the `termmeta` table.

The custom query uses `get_col()` which allows you to get an array of the  `term_ids` where the `meta_key` and the `meta_value` match the values you have in the question. Notice that the query uses `prepare()` which is good practice for security.

More info on `$wpdb` can be found on [its Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Providing you get some results back, you can then loop through them, and using Wordpress' `get_term` and `get_term_link` functions, output the list of links you're looking for.

```
global $wpdb;

// custom query to get all the term_ids from the termmeta table
$query_str  = 'SELECT term_id FROM ' . $wpdb -> prefix . 'termmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %s';
$meta_key   = 'food_type';
$meta_value = 'Cat food';

$term_ids = $wpdb -> get_col( $wpdb -> prepare( $query_str, $meta_key, $meta_value ) );

// if you got results back, loop through them to create a list of links
if( $term_ids ):

    $taxonomy = 'your_taxonomy';

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $term_ids as $id ):

        // get the term object with $id for displaying the name
        $term = get_term( $id, $taxonomy );
        // get the term permalink
        $url  = get_term_link( $term );

        echo '<li>';
        echo  '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $term -> name . '</a>';  
        echo '</li>';

    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';

endif;
```

Comment: Hi shahar, thanks for your answer. Could you please [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/225667/edit) your post to explain what your code does? See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for help on writing a good answer.

Comment: Hi Tim Malone. There are 3 comments already which explain what's happening, the other functions are standard Wordpress functionality which the codex does a good job of explaining. What exactly do you find unclear?

Comment: BTW, I don't see anything at the link that the answer doesn't fulfil. Please explain the issue so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: My apologies - I thought that link covered this but it appears it doesn't! When posting code it's preferable to explain how this resolves the asker's question, rather than just dumping a code block. It's the "teach a man to fish" principle - keeping in mind that many will come across this answer at a later date, possibly with a slightly different question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39364/discussion-between-shahar-and-tim-malone).